# What is the PEP:expected 2 blank lines found 1 in this code in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I tried redoing the spaccing but it still shows the error.

```
  return moves

def available_actions(self):
    """Returns all of the available actions in this room."""
    moves = self.adjacent_moves()
    moves.append(Actions.ViewInventory())

    assert isinstance(moves, object)
    return moves
```

Comment: The PEP formatting guidelines say there should be two empty lines before a function definition

Comment: thanks that was it.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines

Answer (score 1):

From the [PEP 8 relevant portion](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines):

> Surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank
>   lines.
>
> Method definitions inside a class are surrounded by a single blank
>   line.
>
> Extra blank lines may be used (sparingly) to separate groups of
>   related functions. Blank lines may be omitted between a bunch of
>   related one-liners (e.g. a set of dummy implementations).
>
> Use blank lines in functions, sparingly, to indicate logical sections.
>
> Python accepts the control-L (i.e. ^L) form feed character as
>   whitespace; Many tools treat these characters as page separators, so
>   you may use them to separate pages of related sections of your file.
>   Note, some editors and web-based code viewers may not recognize
>   control-L as a form feed and will show another glyph in its place.